# How to set up native resolution to external monitor in Ubuntu(xrandr doesn't work)

Tags: ubuntu

Some time ago I have switched from Win10 to Linux and I have a problem with external monitor now. My configuration includes 3 monitors - laptop's internal one, one with FHD resolution (they both work fine) and the third HP Omen 32" with 2K(2560x1440) resolution. The graphic cards are HD5600 and GTX970m. The problem is that I can't set native 2K resolution for the Omen.
I've tried xrandr --addmode and it even adds new resolution to display settings but when I choose it displays blink and nothing changes. I've tried to use [Persistent resolution using xrandr in VNC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371758/persistent-resolution-using-xrandr-in-vnc) these slight different method too and get all three monitors blacked and not responding before I rebooted my PC. Also I've found an advice to add settings to grub file (video=2560x1440) but it doesn't do anything if I don't change settings in panel when I enter Ubuntu from BIOS and if I do so I have black displays.
I bought the Omen about three months ago and it works fine with Win10 so I believe that there is a way to solve my problem. Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: How is the HP Omen connected?

Comment: By HDMI cable(I do not know version of HDMI)

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that the problem was pixel clock rate! By  default it was set to 312.25MHz, but my hardware can't operate with that rate. But changing command

```
cvt 2560 1440
```

to reduced version

```
cvt -r 2560 1440 60
```

I got 241.5MHz. It bright idea was obtained from [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294846/cant-set-2560x1440-resolution-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-graphics-card) namely by @Adrien Beau.
Accordingly to this website [Monitor Insider](http://monitorinsider.com/cable_bandwidth.html) sufficient pixel clock rate for 2560x1440 60Hz is 234.59MHz so given 241.5MHz is more than enough.

Comment: worked for me too, I have dell 30` with 60 Hz refresh, had had to do new cvt config for 45 Hz and it worked. It's not native refresh speed but still acceptable and I got 2560x1600 via common HDMI cable from hp laptop on ryzen7000 with no graphic card, only integrated amd core